# netcore and platform specific libraries

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm trying to implement some platform abstractions with a netcore project. The idea is to have a Platform.dll library with a known interface and a concrete implementation for each platform to abstract some OS services. Ideally I would like to reference a Windows implementation by default but be able to use the, say, Linux one when executing in Linux.
I thought I could load the dll at runtime, but I seem unable to find a way to do so in netcore 1.1. I found many articles and methods, but none working for a netcore 1.1 project using VS2017.

Assembly.LoadFile is not available.

Assembly.Load only accepts an AssemblyName as parameter.

AssemblyName ctor accepts a string with an assembly name and all its properties are readonly.

AssemblyLoadContext doesn't exist.

AppDomain doesn't exist.

Comment: Check .NET Core 2.0 Preview 1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say `AssemblyLoadContext` doesn't exist: it's in all `netcoreapp` target frameworks from 1.0 up. See https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext

Comment: Just double checked. Class Library and Console netcore projects have no access to AssemblyLoadContext. Only ASP.NET netcore do. Might be an issue with VS2017 and/or netcore install or it is just not there for those projects?